# How to multiple checkbox

Tags: javascript, php

When I check 1 show major1 it's true.

When I check 2 show major2 it's true.

When I check 1 and 2 show major3 it's false.

What do I have to do.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function show(id) {
        if(id == 1) {
            document.getElementById('major1').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('major2').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('major3').style.display='none';
        } else if(id == 2) { 
            document.getElementById('major2').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('major1').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('major3').style.display='none';

        } else if(id == 3) {
            document.getElementById('major3').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('major2').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('major1').style.display='none';
        }
   }
</script>
```

This is html

```
<div id="major1" style="display:none;"><input name="chk[]" id="Checkmajor1" class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1">เทคโนโลยีสารสนเทศ
<input name="chk[]" id="Checkmajor2" class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="2" >วิทยาการคอมพิวเตอร์
<input name="chk[]" id="Checkmajor3" class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="3" >ระบบสารสนเทศ</div>

<div id="major2" style="display:none;">
<input name="chk[]" id="Checkmajor4" class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="4" >ท่องเที่ยว
<input name="chk[]" id="Checkmajor5" class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="5" >อังกฤษเพื่อการสื่อสารสากล</div>

<div id="major3" style="display:none;">
<input name="chk[]" id="Checkmajor1" class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1">เทคโนโลยีสารสนเทศ
<input name="chk[]" id="Checkmajor2" class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="2" >วิทยาการคอมพิวเตอร์
<input name="chk[]" id="Checkmajor3" class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="3" >ระบบสารสนเทศ
<input name="chk[]" id="Checkmajor4" class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="4" >ท่องเที่ยว
<input name="chk[]" id="Checkmajor5" class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="5" >อังกฤษเพื่อการสื่อสารสากล</div>
```

Comment: there's no php here and the html would be a given

Comment: `else { id == 1 && id == 2` that failed; that's for sure.

Comment: How could `id` be both `1` AND `2`

Comment: "*This is PHP*" ... no, that is **HTML**.

Comment: what is your problem ?!

Comment: @TitleTH I saw you adapted your code. Did my answer below help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `function show (params)` takes 1 parameter, stored in the variable `id`

In the next step you check if the value of `id` is 1 `(id == 1)`
- That's fine.

In the next step ( `else if` ) you check if the value of `id` is 2 `(id == 2)` - That's fine too.

**Now comes the culprit from your code sample**

- After `if` or `if else`, there must follow another `if else`, another `else` or nothing. You chose `else`: Therefore you can't have another conditional in there. The last `else` statement only gets triggered if `id` is neither 1 nor 2. If you pass 3 for example, it will get triggered. Also you shouldn't do `(id == 1 && id == 2)`, because it will always return `false` ( 1 variable cannot have 2 different values at the same time )

**OPTION 1**

You delete `id == 1 && id == 2` from your last `else` statement. Then it should show the 3rd element if `id` is not 1 and not 2.

**OPTION 2**

You change `else { id == 1 && id == 2` to `else if ( id == 3 ) {` and pass value 3 as parameter to this function.

But kindof depends on the rest of your code.